# Best way to write SQL delete statement, deleting pairs of records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a MySQL database with just 1 table:
Fields are: blocknr (not unique), btcaddress (not unique), txid (not unique), vin, vinvoutnr, netvalue.

Indexes exist on both btcaddress and txid.

Data in it looks like this:
[image]

I need to delete all "deletable" record pairs. An example is given in red.
Conditions are:

- txid must be the same (there can be more than 2 records with same txid)
- vinvoutnr must be the same
- vin must be different (can have only 2 values 0 and 1, so 1 must be 0 other must be 1)

In a table of 36M records, about 33M records will be deleted.

I've used this:

```
delete t1 
from registration t1 
inner join registration t2 
where t1.txid=t2.txid and t1.vinvoutnr=t2.vinvoutnr and t1.vin<>t2.vin;
```

It works but takes 5 hours.

Maybe this would work too (not tested yet):

```
delete t1 
from registration as t1, registration as t2 
where t1.txid=t2.txid and t1.vinvoutnr=t2.vinvoutnr and t1.vin<>t2.vin;
```

Or do I forget about a delete query and try to make a new table with all non-delatables in and then drop the original ?

Database can be offline for this delete query.

Comment: Don't know if it's the reason for poor performance but I'd expect the join query to look more like this: `delete t1 
from registration t1 
inner join registration t2 on t1.txid=t2.txid and t1.vinvoutnr=t2.vinvoutnr and t1.vin<>t2.vin;`. Or possibly the last clause should still be in the WHERE. Another reason for poor performance can be badly specified indexes.

Comment: Your second query is just legacy syntax for joins, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, you are deleting most of the rows in the table.  That is just really expensive.  A better approach is to empty the table and re-populate it:

```
create table temp_registration as
    <query for the rows to keep here>;

truncate table registration;

insert into registration
    select *
    from temp_registration;
```

Your logic is a bit hard to follow, but I think the logic on the rows to keep is:

```
select r.*
from registration r
where not exists (select 1
                  from registration r2
                  where r2.txid = r.txid and
                        r2.vinvoutnr = r.vinvoutnr and
                        r2.vin <> r.vin
                 );
```

For best performance, you want an index on `registration(txid, vinvoutnr, vin)`.

Comment: Ok I did some performance testing on a smaller set. I took 1.5M records. Of this only 188k remain after deleting the pairs. My original query: 216sec, your query: 59sec. Excellent

Comment: Any additional comments on the indexes to choose that may impact performance ? I now have 2: on btcaddress (but does nothing in this delete), on txid (first 30 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you expect to remove the majority of your data it does sound like the simplest approach would be to create a new table with the correct data and then drop the original table as you suggest. Otherwise ADyson's corrections to the JOIN query might help to alleviate the performance issue.

Comment: Please explain that further. How **exactly** would you add the "correct" data to that new table?